# How can I identify the specific character for a whitespace character?

Tags: whitespace

I have inherited the following code:

```
string.text.replace(" ", " ");
```

There are no comments surrounding the code.

This code doesn't look like it does anything, but I suspect it actually does.

I'd like to refactor the code into something more understandable like:

```
const NEWLINE = " " 
string.text.replace(NEWLINE , " ");
```

```
const NON_BREAKING_SPACE = " " 
string.text.replace(NON_BREAKING_SPACE, " ");
```

**How can I determine that a whitespace character is a particular character?**

I happen to be using JavaScript, but Python, shell or an online tool are also fine - the main issue is determining what the character actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my question, pasting here to help others:

1. Use a [UTF 8 encoder](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode) or a tool like `encodeURI()` to get the character code for each character:

- The first character is 20, `\x20` or `"%20`
- The second character is C2A0, `\xc2\xa0` or `"%C2%A0"`

2. Look up the character code (without the `\x` or `%`) on a [UTF 8 character list](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Which gives:

```
SPACE (U+0020)  20
```

and:

```
NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0) c2a0
```

The mystery code turned out to be:

```
string.text.replace(SPACE, NON_BREAKING_SPACE);
```